# How can I make an Alpine package conflict with another Alpine package?

Tags: package-management, packaging, alpine-linux

Currently [Alpine packages Perl](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/perl?h=master), however that version of Perl is built with the wrong options for my needs. So I want to package a new version Perl built with different configuration/build options.

Is there a mechanism to say that my Perl should conflict with the upstream Perl? I'm reading the [Wiki, *"Creating an Alpine package"*](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Creating_an_Alpine_package) but I don't see anything in there about "Conflicts".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to specify that a package is conflicting in an APKBUILD is by adding the package name prefixed with a '!' to depends (see the [APKBUILD reference](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/APKBUILD_Reference#depends)).

```bsh
depends=".. !perl"
```

What you also might want to do is add a `provides` option:

```bsh
provides="perl=$pkgver-r$pkgrel"
```

This makes sure that any packages that depend on perl can use this package instead.